# Batch: Forfiles that are older than date copy them

Tags: batch-file

i try to create a batch script, that copy all files that are older than a date (DD-MM-YYYY) in another folder.

```
@echo off
set ARCHIV=%DATE:~0,2%%DATE:~2,2%%DATE:~4,6%

mkdir %ARCHIV%

forfiles -p "c:\" -s  -d 01.01.2002 -c "cmd /c copy c:\%ARCHIV%\"
pause
```

The Error Code is: ERROR: ARgument/Option invalid - 'c:\11.06.2014"'.

Tip in "FORFILES /?" to show the Syntax
Please press any key . . .

Does somenone know where my mistake is ?

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `xcopy /D`

> from xcopy /?
>
> /D:mm-dd-yyyy
>                   Copy files changed on or after the specified date.
>                   If no date is given, copy only files whose
>                   source date/time is newer than the destination time.

Comment: same mistake when i try this 
    forfiles -p "c:\" -s  /D:01-01-2002 -c "cmd /c xcopy c:\%ARCHIV%\"

Comment: @Atlantikdiver you dont need to use forfiles : `xcopy /D:01-01-2012 c:\path\to\source\ c:\path\to\destination`